# Where does $\frac{1+q}{3}$ come from?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, bayesian

I am looking at the [solution](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-041sc-probabilistic-systems-analysis-and-applied-probability-fall-2013/unit-iv/lecture-22/MIT6_041SCF13_assn10_sol.pdf) to question 4(d)ii [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-041sc-probabilistic-systems-analysis-and-applied-probability-fall-2013/unit-iv/lecture-22/MIT6_041SCF13_assn10.pdf).  The reasoning goes:

[image: img]

I get the arithmetic before the part boxed in red.  My question is where does $\frac{1+q}{3}$ come from?  I am really perplexed.

Comment: Please add `self-study` and reproduce the entire question in your text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the question,

> (d) For this part, assume $p=2/3$.

$$1-p+q(2p-1)=\frac13+q\left(\frac43-1\right)=\frac{1+q}{3}$$

Comment: Thank you!  I was so absent-minded.